# Deactivate other gameObject's script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using one script for multiple gameObjects. If my current gameObject is triggered, I want the script to be deactivated on all other gameObjects except for current gameObject. I can set current script to be active after I have disabled it. But I do not want it to be enabled as false at all. How do I achieve this?

```
public MyScript[] myScript;

void Start () {
        myScript= FindObjectsOfType (typeof (MyScript)) as MyScript[];
    }

void Activated() {
        for (int i = 0; i < myScript.Length; i++) {
            myScript[i].enabled = false; //All other scripts except for current gameObject's script
        }
```

Comment: This sound like observer pattern. Look into event systems like this one -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gx0Lt4tCDE0

Comment: I saw the video but I do not want an event system. I am triggering the function anyway. My question is how do I disable other instances of the same script except for the current gameObject's script.

Comment: Why you do not want an event system ? That is a proper way of doing these kind of stuff. Otherwise in your for loop you need to check like if(triggeredObject != gameObject) then disable object.

Comment: Could you please provide solutions for both? Using Events and using the if(myScript != gameObject) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Event System

Something like this.

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<GameObject> Triggered;

    private void Start()
    {
        MyScript.Triggered += OnTriggered;
    }

    private void OnTriggered(GameObject triggeredGameObject)
    {
        if (triggeredGameObject != gameObject)
        {
            enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Triggered?.Invoke(gameObject);
    }
}
```

2. Your Way

You need to pass your triggered gameobject into the Activated function somehow so you make a comparison

```
    public MyScript[] myScript;
    
    void Start () {
            myScript= FindObjectsOfType (typeof (MyScript)) as MyScript[];
        }
    
    void Activated(GameObject triggeredGameObject)// pass the triggered gameobject here
 {
            for (int i = 0; i < myScript.Length; i++) 
{
           if(triggeredGameObject != myScript[i].gameObject)
                myScript[i].enabled = false;
            }
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. If a button is pressed, how do I reference it under triggeredGameObject?

Comment: You can assign it through editor where you assign button's onclick functionality if i understand your question correctly.